# Reset MYSQL database to core data (docker)

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, microservices

In order to test my nodejs microservice architecture I am trying to build the entire architecture with docker. Now I want to run tests with `newman` (postman). In the before-each hook, so before every http test request, the database(s) should have a predefined dataset.

So now to the core question: Is there a simple way to reset the entire database, so that the architecture stays (does it anyway) but the data in the database gets reset to a predefined state. (Maybe via sql statement?)
I read about `ROLLBACK`, but I think this is not going to work due to the fact that the `ROLLBACK` is going to happen from another service within my architecture. Also there is not only one mysql request happening, but multiple msql request during one http test request.

Regards

Comment: You could write internal integration tests which use the/a database but rollback any changes (through a transaction).

Comment: You'd have to tear down and recreate the database after each test.  In a Docker setup you can simplify this a little bit by creating a tar file of the database data directory, but it's probably too slow and difficult to do it for every single test.  You might use your application's API as part of the test to create the expected data, rather than assuming it's there.

Comment: @DavidMaze I also thought about tearing down and rebuilding it, but as you mentioned, it will be slow. Is creating the needed data via the API actually a valid method? IMO I am relying on something, that is also tested in the test bundle. Do you think it would be good to call the API point of my DB service to create the needed data instead of calling the API gateway?